# Run PowerShell Script on a Mounted Drive to Copy Files

Tags: powershell, access-denied, scheduled-tasks, windows10

I have written a PowerShell script that copies files from one mapped drive to another. Script runs fine when I run through PowerShell or command prompt. It mounts the both drives first and then wait for 10 second and then copies the files.

I now want to run the same script in Task scheduler but getting error.

Logon failure: the user has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer.

[image]

Task is configured to run with my account and I can run script in command prompt without any error.
Is there any special permissions required for Task scheduler?

The script I used to map the drive

```
$LibraryURL =http://corpapps/cloud/documentLibary"
$Network = new-object -ComObject WScript.Network
$Network.MapNetworkDrive('D:', $LibraryURL)
```

Answer (score -1):

Our Windows Task scheduler's PS script runs with a service account that has to be granted  **Log on as a service** privilege in the Local Security Policy on the Server.

Local Security Policy=> Local Policies => User Rights Assignments => Log on as a service.

You can check if your account has that privilege on your local computer.

You can try also granting "Log on as a batch job"

Comment: but which service account needs permissions? The account I used to trigger the job as shown in picture?

Comment: I already have log on as a service rights but i don't have log on as a batch job rights.